# Get live data of nse stocks of all symbols in python/Django

Tags: python, django, stockquotes, alpha-vantage

I m working on a stock prediction project. This is how I want:

To show all the stocks available in Nifty50, Nifty100 or so and then the user will select the stock to predict the high and low price of a stock on next day only.

I m using Django.

**What I have done till now:**
I m able to display a list of stock.

```
def index(request):
    api_key = 'myAPI_Key'

    url50 = 'https://archives.nseindia.com/content/indices/ind_nifty50list.csv'
    url100 = 'https://archives.nseindia.com/content/indices/ind_nifty100list.csv'
    url200 = 'https://archives.nseindia.com/content/indices/ind_nifty200list.csv'

    sfifty = requests.get(url50).content
    shundred = requests.get(url100).content
    stwohundred = requests.get(url200).content

    nifty50 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(sfifty.decode('utf-8')))
    nifty100 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(shundred.decode('utf-8')))
    nifty200 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(stwohundred.decode('utf-8')))

    nifty50 = nifty50['Symbol']
    nifty100 = nifty100['Symbol']
    nifty200 = nifty200['Symbol']



    context = {
        'fifty': nifty50,
        'hundred': nifty100,
        'twohundred': nifty200
               }

    return render(request, 'StockPrediction/index.html', context)
```

**What I want:**
I want to get the live data of all stocks `open`, `high`,`LTP`,`Change`, `Volume`.by mean of live data is that it will change as per stock values will change.

Please Help!

Answer (score 1):

You must combine `Ajax/Jquery` like code below to periodically get data and update values in `DOM`  :

```
(function getStocks() {
    $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "url to your view",
            success: function (data) {
                // here you can get data from backend and do changes like
                // changing color by the data coming from your view.
            }
        }).then(function() {           // on completion, restart
       setTimeout(getStocks, 30000);  // function refers to itself
    });
})();
```

But be careful about making too requests, you must choose proper interval right in this line `setTimeout(getStocks, "proper interval");`

And in your `view` you should put queries into a `JSON` format something like this :

```
return JsonResponse({'stocks': stocks})
```

here `stocks` must be in `json` format.